# How to show DOMPDF footer - Page number and Page count in all pages except last page

Tags: php, dompdf

I am using DOMPDF to generate PDF file. 
I want footer(Page number and Page count) in all pages except last page. 
currently i am having this code

```
    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $html = ob_get_contents();
    $dompdf->load_html($html);
    $dompdf->render();
    $canvas = $dompdf->get_canvas();
    $font = Font_Metrics::get_font("helvetica", "12");                  
    $canvas->page_text(500, 770, "Page {PAGE_NUM} - {PAGE_COUNT}", $font, 10, array(0,0,0));
    $canvas->page_text(260, 770, "Canny Pack", $font, 10, array(0,0,0));
    $canvas->page_text(43, 770, $date, $font, 10, array(0,0,0));
    $pdf = $dompdf->output();
```

the above code in showing footer in all pages. but i dont want footer in last page.

can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: You would have to use a `page_script` instead. Just an FYI, I'll try to provide an example when I have the time.

Answer (score 3):

The `page_text()` methods runs on all pages without restriction. If you use the `text()` method in combination with the `page_script()` method you can programmatically determine the pages on which you want to insert the text.

Something like the following should work:

```
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$canvas = $dompdf->get_canvas();
$canvas->page_script('
  if ($pdf->get_page_number() != $pdf->get_page_count()) {
    $font = Font_Metrics::get_font("helvetica", "12");                  
    $pdf->text(500, 770, "Page {PAGE_NUM} - {PAGE_COUNT}", $font, 10, array(0,0,0));
    $pdf->text(260, 770, "Canny Pack", $font, 10, array(0,0,0));
    $pdf->text(43, 770, $date, $font, 10, array(0,0,0));
  }
');
$pdf = $dompdf->output();
```

Comment: Just a question, where do you put these lines of code? In the controller or in the view itself?

Comment: I guess that depends on your framework. When I set up dompdf with a CakePHP-based site I put it in a view. But I'd first check to see if someone has already gone through the trouble and created a module/plugin to handle PDF rendering.